# graphing a social network graph from data in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, igraph, social-networking

I have a dataframe of 380 observations of 9 variables. The data represents the cooperation between persons doing similar projects. In the first column is the main node and the other columns represent the persons s/he cooperated with on a project which each column representing one person. So if perchance researcher in row 1 column 1 cooperated with five persons, their names will be in five columns, and if researcher in row 2 column 1 cooperated with 3 persons their names will be in the other three columns. Obviously there will be many empty columns as not all researchers cooperate with same amount of persons. With this data, how do I plot this into a network graph?

dataframe example:

```
data <- data.frame(
author_1 = c('John', 'Kerry', 'Michelle', 'Joan', 'Paul'),
author_2 = c('Joan', 'Rick', 'N/A', 'Terrence', 'Collin'),
author_3 = c('Terrence', 'Michelle', 'Michelle', 'Joan', 'Paul'),
author_4 = c('Michelle', 'Collin', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'Phillips'))
```

I tried using graph.data.frame but that only gives connection between the first two columns.

Comment: Are there 380 individuals or 9?

Comment: Please add a reproducible example.

Comment: 380 represents the amount of research projects. for some projects there are only one researcher, while for others they are as much as nine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try with the `ggraph` package, but we have to arrange well the data.

```
# this are your data
data <- data.frame(
author_1 = c('John', 'Kerry', 'Michelle', 'Joan', 'Paul'),
author_2 = c('Joan', 'Rick', 'N/A', 'Terrence', 'Collin'),
author_3 = c('Terrence', 'Michelle', 'Michelle', 'Joan', 'Paul'),
author_4 = c('Michelle', 'Collin', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'Phillips'))

# here you load some nice package
library(tidyr)      # to tidy the data
library(ggraph)     # to plot nice network data with the semantic of ggplot
library(tidygraph)  # to work with networks
library(ggrepel)    # to not have overlapping labels
```

First, you should prepare your data. Due you have a father row, `author_1`, and sons, you can manage to do this for each combinations of `author_1` and `author_n`, due you should have only one columns. It clearly works also if you have not a hierarchical dataset. You should have all the combinations of doubles father-sons for each rows, and `rbind()` do it, merging all the combinations (easier to do than to explain).

```
edges <-rbind(
expand(data, nesting(author_1,author_2))  %>%  `colnames<-`(c("a", "b")),  # for 1 and 2, we do all the combinations and give name a and b
expand(data, nesting(author_1,author_3))  %>%  `colnames<-`(c("a", "b")),  # for 1 and 3, we do all the combinations and give name a and b
expand(data, nesting(author_1,author_4))  %>%  `colnames<-`(c("a", "b"))   # for 1 and 3, we do all the combinations and give name a and b
)
edges
# A tibble: 15 x 2
   a        b       
   <fct>    <fct>   
 1 Joan     Terrence
 2 John     Joan    
 3 Kerry    Rick    
 4 Michelle N/A     
 5 Paul     Collin  
 6 Joan     Joan    
 7 John     Terrence
 8 Kerry    Michelle
 9 Michelle Michelle
10 Paul     Paul    
11 Joan     N/A     
12 John     Michelle
13 Kerry    Collin  
14 Michelle N/A     
15 Paul     Phillips
```

Remember, if you would plot the N/A, you left this as is, in other hand you add at the end  this `%>% filter(b != 'N/A')` .

Now we manage the data to put them in the graph:

```
# create edges
edges1 <- edges%>% group_by(a,b) %>% summarise(weight = sum(n()))

# create nodes
nodes <- rbind(data.frame(researcher = edges$a, n = 1),data.frame(researcher = edges$b, n = 1)) %>%
  group_by(researcher) %>%
  summarise(n = sum(n))

# now we have to have the match between edges and nodes
edges1$a <- match(edges1$a, nodes$researcher) 
edges1$b <- match(edges1$b, nodes$researcher)

# declare the data as graph data
tidy <- tbl_graph(nodes = nodes, edges = edges1, directed = T)
tidy <- tidy %>% 
  activate(edges) %>% 
  arrange(desc(weight)
  ) 

# now the plot: you have several options to do, here a basic one
ggraph(tidy, layout = "gem") +     
geom_node_point(aes(size=n)) +                          # size of the node the frequency
geom_edge_link(aes(width = weight),                     # here you set the edges
                                                        # thickness as frequency
               arrow = arrow(length = unit(4, 'mm')),   # arrows, if you want
               end_cap = circle(3, 'mm'), alpha = 0.8) + 
scale_edge_width(range = c(0.2, 2)) +
geom_text_repel(aes(x = x, y=y , label=researcher))
```

[image]

That should be coherent with `data` and:

```
> edges1
# A tibble: 14 x 3
# Groups:   a [?]
       a     b weight
   <int> <int>  <int>
 1     1     1      1
 2     1     7      1
 3     1     9      1
 4     2     1      1
 5     2     9      1
 6     2     4      1
 7     3     6      1
 8     3     8      1
 9     3     4      1
10     4     7      2
11     4     4      1
12     5     6      1
13     5     5      1
14     5    10      1
> nodes
# A tibble: 10 x 2
   researcher     n
   <fct>      <dbl>
 1 Joan           5
 2 John           3
 3 Kerry          3
 4 Michelle       6
 5 Paul           4
 6 Collin         2
 7 N/A            3
 8 Rick           1
 9 Terrence       2
10 Phillips       1
```